# How can I type the props in the react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-props

How can I type the props in the react typescript ? I'm getting the error Property 'authors' does not exist on type '[Props] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts. I'm expecting to pass an array wich consists of name and password keys.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-24-04-forked-eg91s5?file=/src/components/Login.tsx:229-274

```js
type Props = {
  authors: {
    name: string;
    password: string;
  }[];
};

const Login: FC<[Props]> = ({ authors }) => {
  return (
  ...
  )
}
```

, even though I'm passing the props.

Comment: `FC<Props>` should works

Comment: Change `FC<[Props]>` to `FC<Props>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `[Props]` to `Props` like following

```
const Login: FC<Props> = ({ authors }) => { ... }
```

Now it will work because it's expecting object not array, we will pass an object like `<Login authors={authors} />`. Now authors will be an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You defined IUser interface and defined name,password states with IUser type that's will cause a problem because when you define this:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<IUser>("");
// name will expected to be 
name = {
    name: 'name',
    password: 'password'
}
```

and that's wrong because name,password is a string so try to define it like this:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<IUser["name"]>("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState<IUser["password"]>("");
```

then you have to fix passing authors to your FC component:

```
const Login: FC<Props> // instead of <[Props]>
```

last thing you have to fix this type to match the type of data you passed it from App.tsx:

```
type Props = {
    authors: {
       author_name: string; // instead of name
       password: string;
    }[];
};


// because you are passing and comparing here with author_name not with name

const userData = authors.find(
  (user) => user.author_name === name && user.password === password
);
```

and you passed it from App like this:

```
const Authors = [
   {
      id: "001",
      author_name: "John Smith", // not a name
      password: "123"
   }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `type` or `interface` to describe props.
Usually `interface` is used for describing `objects`.
It's also a nice convention to start `interfaces` with letter `I` and `types` with `T`.

```
interface IAuthor {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

const Login = ({ authors }: { authors: IAuthor[] ): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

In the above example, the `Login` component expects a prop `authors` that is an array of `objects` described by `IAuthor` e.g.

```
authors = [
  {
    name: "Spiderman"
    password: "maryjane"
  },
  { 
    name: "Superman"
    password: "loislane"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        type Props = {
          authors: {
            name: string;
            password: string;
          }[];
        };
        
        const Login: FC<Props> = ({ authors }) => {
          const history = useHistory();
          const [name, setName] = useState<IUser["name"]>("");
          const [password, setPassword] = useState<IUser["password"]>("");
    
    
    please use these syntaxes to fix the error. There are three errors in your code that I found.

FC<Props>
<IUser["name"]>
<IUser["password"]>
```